# Can I add a "edit node" link as field in a node?

Tags: entities

I need to have the "edit node" link as a field so that I can manage its display.

Can I do this?

Update:
I created the field but the token code is printed instead of its value.
The code you see in the capture is printed: `http://misite.com/node/%5Bnode%3Anid%5D/edit`

Capture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As variant, You can create custom code field via display suite module.

Example field code for node edit link:

```
 

print l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . arg(1) . '/edit');
```

Comment: I created the field but the token code is printed instead of its value.
The code you see in the capture (at the bottom of my question) is printed: `http://misite.com/node/%5Bnode%3Anid%5D/edit`

Comment: Oh, tokens are not working with display suite php text format

You can use this code:

 print l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . arg(1) . '/edit');

Answer (score 4):

You could also check to see if the user has access before printing the edit link.
`<?php
  if (node_access('update', $entity)) {
    print l(t('Edit'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit');
  }
?>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use $entity->nid when you want to print the nid in display suite format. With $entity->nid the correct nid of each item is printed when used in teaserlists.

```
<?php print l(t('Edit this node'), 'node/' . $entity->nid . '/edit'); ?>
```