# Edit button in teasers

Tags: nodes

i'm using display suite and views in one of my teaser content type and i'm trying to add an EDIT button right in the teaser, but i can't find the function to do this. So i came here to ask for help. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are using Display Suite module, you can simply create a new "Custom Field" and use the "Code field"(Add Code field) to generate the apropriate code to edit. Enable the Entities to Node and in the field code add this code and hit save:

```
<a href="[node:edit-url]">EDIT</a>
```

PS: As you can see, i'm using a token to generate the edit path of the node, so you need to have [token module](https://drupal.org/project/token) enabled. Make sure that you are adding this in the teaser display

Comment: Better answer found here @ http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/130579/9150

This will check the user permission also.

Answer (score 2):

The edit function is usually provided in teasers with contextual links.

Activate the optional core module, and when the teaser is displayed, a contextual links icon will be displayed at the upper right corner of the rendered teaser.

Comment: Hello Triskelion, I have contextual link enabled and still nothing (no edit link) in the teaser. Can you provide some more details? Thank you

Comment: Have you given yourself the permission to _Use contextual links_ under `admin/people/permissions`? Also, the link only appears on _mouse over_ the teaser.

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: Just a note: If you have "Devel Theme developer" module enabled, the Contextual link will not be shown

Answer (score 0):

In Views add filed 'Content: Edit link' and on teaser field go to 'Rewrite results > Rewrite the output of this field' in box use 'Replacement patterns' below and write something like [your-teaser-field-replacement]...[edit_node].

Instead '...' you can use anything or just space.

Rearrange fields and set 'Content: Edit link' field above your teaser field.

On filed 'Content: Edit link' check 'Exclude from display'.

You can use css to set button instead text on edit link.

More info on [THIS](https://drupal.psu.edu/content/rewrite-results-views) and [THIS](http://www.webomelette.com/views-rewrite-results-drupal-7) link...

Comment: There is no _Teaser_ field. He is using rendered content and individual fields like _Edit link_ will not display.

Comment: With your sugestion, I can't find the 'Content: Edit link' in the View fields. I'm using the last version of Views module